# Dialog Spinner does not return value

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

I have a dialog setup that has two spinners connected to a cursor. I have worked through a couple of problems with the help of this site, but I can not seem to get past this point. Everything I find are things I have already tried. 
The problem is that when I click on a spinner selection or click Submit to exit the dialog, the spinner value is not the value it should be. I am getting the package name with some code. I am trying to get the string from the spinner with `.getSelectedItem().toString();`
I currently have the code set up to use `onItemSelected`, but before that I tried to use the `getItemSelected` once Submit was clicked. Neither seem to work.

Here is the code for this section.
At the end the values are going into a textview. The value shown is "android.database.sqlite.sqliteCursor@414175e0"

Any ideas?

```
 private void transfer() {
     dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth);
     dialog.setContentView(R.layout.transfer_dialog);
     dialog.setTitle(R.string.transfer_accounts);
     Button btnCancel = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
     Button btnSubmit = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

     Cursor load_spinner = mDbHelper.spinnerAccounts();
     startManagingCursor(load_spinner);

     String[] columns = new String[] { RegisterDbAdapter.ACCOUNTS_ACCOUNT };
     int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

     SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, load_spinner, columns, to);
     mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     spinnerFrom = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinnerFrom);
     spinnerTo = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTo);
     spinnerFrom.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     spinnerTo.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     dialog.show();

     spinnerFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
             fromAccount = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
         }
         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }
        }); 
     spinnerTo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
             toAccount = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
         }
         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }
        });
     btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 dialog.dismiss(); 
            }
          });

     btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 tvFrom.setText(fromAccount);
                 tvTo.setText(toAccount);
                 dialog.dismiss();
            }
          });

 }
```

Comment: can you do fromAccount = parent.getCursor()?

Comment: I was unable to enter this line. The .getCursor part was not available to me in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it to work. Thanks for the suggestions, I really do appreciate them, but they didn't work for me. I am not sure why the code will not return the value, since the way I tried it supposedly works for others.
Anyway, I found a way to get my values by using 'Long arg3'. Since it holds the rowId of the value in the table, I used that to return the selection in the spinner. I am posting the code for this below.
Thanks again.

The code from the selected spinner:

```
  spinnerFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
             getAccountName(arg3);
             fromAccount = returnAccount;
             }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }
        });
```

And here is the method I wrote to return the value I wanted. I put it a separate method because it is getting used from multiple spinners. The code:

```
 private void getAccountName(long arg3) {
     if (returnAccount != null){
         returnAccount = null;
     }
        RegisterDbAdapter tAdaptor = new RegisterDbAdapter(this);
        tAdaptor.open();
        Cursor tCursor = tAdaptor.fetchAccount(arg3);
        startManagingCursor(tCursor);
        returnAccount = tCursor.getString(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate adapters for two spinners.

You are only using one... each time you make a selection, the adapter sets your selection to your choice ( for both of the spinners since you have the same adapter backing each one ).

Create a second adapter and things should work more like you expect.

Also, try this in your `onItemSelected` method (using the parameter names you show):

```
String fromAccount = parent.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
```

Comment: I tried adding a second adaptor, but there is no difference. One other thing that is most likely related. In debug mode, when a break point stops the execution at the code that should set values to the textview, I would hover over the string to see the value. Instead of a value, I see the type and context. ( "String com.myapp.example.blah.blah.tvFrom" ) Same as you would see if the code did not run yet.

Comment: Updated.my answer.  Let me know if there's still a problem.

Comment: Once I got the code to work, I went back and removed the second adapter to see if it would work either way. It does work with one adapter feeding both spinners or with the separate adapters. I see no difference either way. Also, I tried the line of code you supplied, with the exception of the preceding 'String' (I have that called before onCreate) and it also saves the Map location of the value I want, instead of the actual value.

Comment: So how'd you get the code to work?  Is the code in the question above updated and functional now?

Comment: Working code is show below, in "my" answer. Being new to posting here, when this was originally done, I wasn't sure how to best post the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use your cursor to get the String you want. Arg2 should be the selected position. Use it to place your cursor to the right data row and use the getstring method of the cursor to get the string from the database column.